# How to find the language and create Push down automaton if the A is continuously looping ? and will PDA accept L produced without A

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

Let us consider the following Context-Free Grammar

G = ({S,A,B,C,D},{a, b}, S, P)
with production rules P:

S → SSA | Bb

A → BSA

B → A | Cb

C → AD | Cb | ɛ

D → a | b | ɛ

Let L be the language produced by G. Design a single state Pushdown Automaton that accepts
L. Indicate the relevant functions of transitions and draw the Automaton.

The solution I came up with is that L will be **(b^n: n>1)** and that A won't produce any strings 
)

Example:
{bbbb,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,bb,bbb

or Remove A and the L produced will be **(a+b^n)**

ALso What will happen at AD?

Comment: A strange grammar indeed. (Dead certain the problem was stated as presented in this question?) What happens to the $B$ in the $BSA A$ is bound to be replaced with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [this explanation](https://www.javatpoint.com/automata-cfg-to-pda-conversion) on how to transform a CFG into a (1 state) PDA

Comment: Whoops the link was removed from the post. I will add it in a second